# Working with fixed-width (flat) files with multiple rows ended by a new line in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, fixed-width

I am fairly new to pyspark and still trying to find my way around it. Kindly help, I am trying to extract data from a flat file using pyspark and assign it column names using the length and position.
Then later I have to convert it to parquet format on azure synapse. I have been struggling with getting it right.

I have used the suggestions provided here [https://stackoverflow.com/a/74074532/16562593](https://stackoverflow.com) to come up with the following code:

```py
df = spark.read.text("PMNTINSTR_RES_24052023163601_00010.txt")
col_idx = {"MDRecordType": {"Position": 1, "Length":2},\
    "Channel": {"Position": 3, "Length":10},\
    "MessageType": {"Position": 13, "Length":20},\
    "ISOCountryCode": {"Position": 33, "Length":2},\
    "SWIFTBIC": {"Position": 35, "Length":11},\
    "InterchangeId": {"Position": 46, "Length":31},\
    "ProcessingIndicator": {"Position": 77, "Length":10},\
    "TimeStamp": {"Position": 87, "Length":20},\
    "INRecordType": {"Position": 1, "Length":2},\
    "InstructionId": {"Position": 3, "Length":31},\
    "InterchangeId": {"Position": 34, "Length":31},\
    "Source": {"Position": 75, "Length":10},\
    "SenderBIC": {"Position": 85, "Length":11}}
df.select(*map(lambda x: trim(df.value.substr(col_idx[x]['Position'], col_idx[x]   ['Length'])).alias(x), col_idx)).show()
```

and fixed width file looks like this (I have truncated some of the rows for practicality)

```
MDDUMMY      FILEFEEDBACK             ZAXXXXXXXX   49752700                                 20230524163505                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
IN49752700                       DUMMY      XXXXXXXX   20230524163505      1002                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
IS49752700                      49752700                       20230524163505      20230524T                                                                      0000100001
```

The Output is

```
+------------+--------+------------+--------------+---------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------+------------+--------------------+------+------+
|MDRecordType| Channel| MessageType|ISOCountryCode| SWIFTBIC|       InterchangeId|ProcessingIndicator|     TimeStamp|INRecordType|       InstructionId|Status|Source|
+------------+--------+------------+--------------+---------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------+------------+--------------------+------+------+
|          MD|   DUMMY|FILEFEEDBACK|            ZA| XXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXX   49752700|                   |20230524163505|          MD|DUMMY     FILEFEE...|      |   202|
|          IN|49752700|            |             C|PARSDUMMY|          CPARSDUMMY|                   |              |          IN|            49752700|      |      |
```

Desired is

```
+------------+--------+------------+--------------+---------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------+------------+--------------------+------+---------+
|MDRecordType| Channel| MessageType|ISOCountryCode| SWIFTBIC|       InterchangeId|ProcessingIndicator|     TimeStamp|INRecordType|       InstructionId|Source|SenderBIC|
+------------+--------+------------+--------------+---------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------+------------+--------------------+------+---------+
|          MD|   DUMMY|FILEFEEDBACK|            ZA| XXXXXXXX|            49752700|                   |20230524163505|          IN|            49752700|DUMMY | XXXXXXXX|
```

Please assist how can I go about it to read all the records correctly to get to the desired output